# How to connect Kml layer + Autocomplete in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, kml

I have a question about SDK Google maps in Android

I have a Autocomplete Place that works perfectly. When i write some text in the input, google show me locations, and when i click on any print coordinates.

Question:
Is there any way to know if those coordinates are in a polygon of a Google my maps kml file?

I tried:

```
KmlLayer(map,id for local file, context)
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml

The problem is that i need the local kml file on my local repository. I need to get KML file from URL with a map id (https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=XXXXrsxRFHqpMEmYXXXXX)
That "mid", can change, since sometimes I will need to use another kml file with a different url.

Also, Autocomplete documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

Thank you everyone.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks**

Comment: I was able to collect the kml with the following link `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?mid=XXXXrsxRFHqpMEmYXXXXX&forcekml=1`  instead of  `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=XXXXrsxRFHqpMEmYXXXXX`